# How to get groups and their roles/permissions on each individual subsite, without including groups from child elements (such as libraries)?

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, groups, roles

*Using CSOM and C#, how can I get the groups that have permissions on a site along with their roles, given that I have the name of the subsite?* 
Language might be a barrier here, and I tend to explain things more difficult than they really are. So. **To get a visual idea of what I'm trying to achieve, please just do the following:**
While on a SharePoint site (any site, doesn't matter if it is the top site level or a subsite) on which you have administrator rights, click on the settings icon at the top right and choose "Shared with...". Then click on "Advanced". 
You then see a list of groups and their roles (like "Edit", "Read", "Contribute" and so on). 
**That is what I am trying to retrieve using C#.** A list that shows just that.

So far I managed to get a nice list of all groups in a subsite along with their roles, but the list also shows me the groups for each and every page library, document library and list library in the subsite. Basically it shows me all the groups, from all underlaying libraries. And that's not the result I was searching for. 
So if there is a way to get the groups for each individual subsite, if possible even for each individual library (because I'll be needing that in the future), then that would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance for your time!
**EDIT:**
In reply to Brandon C., I adapted your code to this:

```
if (web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
   RoleAssignmentCollection rCol = web.RoleAssignments;
   context.Load(rCol);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   foreach (RoleAssignment rAssign in rCol)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(rAssign.Member + " - " + rAssign.RoleDefinitionBindings);
   }
}
```

However in the console I then get this for each role assignment in the role assignment collection:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Principal - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            var ogroup = context.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup;
            var mgroup = context.Web.AssociatedMemberGroup;
            var vgroup = context.Web.AssociatedVisitorGroup;

            context.Load(ogroup);
            context.Load(mgroup);
            context.Load(vgroup);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            var currentWebGroups = new List<string>() {ogroup.LoginName, mgroup.LoginName, vgroup.LoginName};

            var assignments = context.Web.RoleAssignments;
            context.Load(assignments, assignment => assignment.Include(role => role.Member, role => role.RoleDefinitionBindings));
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var roleAssignment in assignments.Where(assignment => currentWebGroups.Contains(assignment.Member.LoginName)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(roleAssignment.Member.LoginName + " - " + roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.First().Name);
            }
```

Comment: That also just returns "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Principal - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection" in the console.

Comment: Are you sure? I have tested this code in my environment this works OK.

Comment: I assigned roleAssignment.Member.LoginName to a variable and now it does, sorry for the misunderstanding! Still showing all groups from all child elements as well though.

Comment: I little bit changed own code and added to this getting and filtering VisitorGroup,MembersGroup and OwnersGroup

Comment: I think that it's context.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup that should be assigned to ogroup. But I now get a new error: "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object on server. The object is associated with property AssociatedVisitorGroup." on the line where you assign the groups to currentWebGroups.

Comment: Does problem repeated on other webs?

Comment: Yes, happens on other sub sites too.

Comment: Could you share your source code? That I could reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what to share. I copied your code and it doesn't work with me. It just gives me the groups of the subsite and any underlaying list or library. My code is over 700 lines long, what exactly do you want me to share?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I answered a question of yours earlier that was similar to this, so if what I am posting is pretty much te same and wrong, just let me know :)

It should work with this, right?

Change the write-host to whatever you want to store the string as, or something

Try doing it this way then?  I don't have a way to write the code, so I have no way of checking if my stuff is correct, so take it at face value :)

```
if(list.hasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
   SPRoleAssignmentsCollection myRoleCollection = list.RoleAssignments;
   foreach (SPRoleAssignment myRole in myRoleCollection)  {

      write-host myRole.Member.Name " - ";
      foreach (SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition in myRoleCollection.RoleDefinitionBindings)
      {
         write-host roleDefinition.Name ", ";
      }
   }
 }
```

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to get the role name printed, but that'll print every group in the subsite I think.

Comment: It is a bit similar yes but the questions aren't the same. In the previous question I needed to find how to get the groups and their roles from a subsite, but I didn't held in account it would also give me the groups and roles of all the child elements of the subsite. So hence the reason why I posted a new question, this time to figure out how to get groups for just the subsite and not the child elements. :) I'll try out your code again!

Comment: I adapted your code but I can't seem to get details on the member of the role assignment, and I couldn't add Role so I added RoleDefinitionBindings instead.

Comment: Now I'm not an expert at Powershell and c# script, but I took a look at your previous code from the question I answered last, and I think I see your problem.  You include the line foreach (Group g2 in o1), and then check roles based on that.  I think in that way, it will show roles by group for everything they are a part of, not just for the current web you are looking at.

Comment: I'm not using Powershell actually, just C#. And indeed in my previous question I did loop through the groups in the collection and that is indeed why I get all the groups, but I couldn't figure out to get a list of only the groups on the subsite, without including all the groups from the child elements.

Comment: Try using my second code.  If that doesn't do it, then I have no idea :\

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives the same result in the console, and I can't cast an object of type Principal to Group. :(

Comment: Now it's a matter of getting it right for myself.  Are you able to use SPPermissionCollection?  Here is a link to the page.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sppermissioncollection.aspx

Comment: Wait! I figured out how to get a result in the console. Without using the groupForRole element, if I just print "princ.Title" to the console then I get a name of the group. Unfortunately it still shows me all the groups from all elements in the subsite, and not just those unique groups added to just the subsite and not its child elements. But it's a start.

Comment: Does princ.Roles work as well?  Also, is it that you just want the permissions on a signle list?  Like to add elements and such?  Instead of using $web, you can do $list instead.  I think that way, it won't get the document.

Comment: There is no princ.Roles. I'm not sure if a subsite can be seen as a list, but initially yes I sortof want to get just the groups and their permissions on each element (so each subsite to begin with, and eventually each list or library too).

Comment: Oh, so, instead of $web from your last code, why not just parse through lists?  The web will include the list, library, page, everything.

Comment: I could indeed parse through lists... Didn't think about that earlier. But then again, how can I get the groups for the subsite? I need those too. :(

Comment: You can have two functions I suppose.  One function to parse through the list, and another to go through the subsites.  Or, if you have the name of the subsite you want, pass it as a parameter to the function, and grab the list name you need from that site.

Comment: I'll try, will get back to this post when I've made progress! Thanks so far! :)

Comment: Yup, sorry for the long chain of messages.  Like I said, I have no way to test the code currently.